# Can i configure the Spring MVC application so that when ever i run the application, the controller or any method should be called automatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have developed a spring application with rest controller which will have only one GET method.
Can i configure the Spring MVC application so that when ever i run the application, the controller or any method should be called automatically with out hitting the api from browser(Just like stand alone application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a bean that implements `org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner` interface.

E.g.

```
@Component
public class MyRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
@Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // Do stuff here at startup
    }
}
```

As this is a regular Spring component, you can use field or constructor injection to inject other Spring components.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an application event listener to do work after startup. Add this code in any of your components:

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void init( ApplicationReadyEvent ev ) {
    //after startup
}
```

See more at [Application Events and Listeners](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners)